# How to resize a composition image using bash in Imagemagick and Facedetect

Tags: python, bash

Just working on adding smiley faces to lots of different costumes using face detection (Facedetect) and Imagemagick.

I got the smileface to be composited to the suited people using composite, but the face is constrained in the facedetected rectangle.

How do I enlarge it to cover the head?  Here's my current code below:

I enlarged the head ok by using w+200 h+200 but it was badly positioned. I need something that works consistently

```
for file in facedetect/*.jpg; do
name=$(basename "$file")
i=0
facedetect  "$file" | while read -r x y w h; do
convert   "$file" smileface.png -geometry "${w}x${h}+${x}+${y}"  
-composite "faces/${name%.*}_${i}.${name##*.}" 
i=$((i+1))
done
done
```

Comment: PNG files may contain a virtual canvas. That may cause an improper offset. So put +repage after smileface.png. If that fails, post your example images. Are the offsets from the top-left or bottom-left or center? When you change the size of the smileface, assuming the offsets are from the top-left, you must compensate for the change in the upper left corner of the smileface, also. The changes to x and y should be half the difference in the dimensions. So use x-100 and y-100. Does that work?

Comment: Thanks fmw42 for the helpful suggestions.  Yes, I just tried the -100 suggestion and it was quite unexpected.  It doesn't seem to want to go northwest at all.  I did the +repage also and it does not seem to do anything as far as I can see.  I have 3 body samples I am experimenting with, and they are different in dimension and do come up with quite different results in terms of how far away the smiley is from the real head.  Sorry, I couldn't work out how to post an image here. Perhaps I should use percentages instead of +200 or find another way to make the results consistent across pictures?

Comment: `@Kk Lam`. You do not have enough points yet to post images. But you can post to some free hosting service and put the URLs here. If you post your image, smileyface and the w,h,x,y for those, I can try to see what is the correct code or the issue.

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestion.  Heres my documentation: https://sites.google.com/view/facedetect-imagemagick/home   Hope it is viewable. Best. KK

Answer (score 0):

I would do that in ImageMagick by doing computations to change your coordinates so that they are center relative to the smiley image. That way you can use -gravity center. That way, when the smiley image changes size, the position to place it is unchanged.

Large Image:

[image]

Smiley Image:

[image]

Lets assume that you get upper left relative coordinates xul,yul for the placement of the smiley in the larger image. We then want to compute the center of the smiley image relative to those coordinates. Once we have that, the coordinates relative to the center of the large image would be those minus half the dimensions of the large image. (The +repage is to ensure that any virtual canvas is removed from the smiley PNG image. JPG does not have a virtual canvas)

```
xul=255
yul=175
xc=`convert smiley.png +repage -format "%[fx:$xul + w/2]\n" info:`
yc=`convert smiley.png +repage -format "%[fx:$yul + h/2]\n" info:`
offx=`convert actor.jpg -format "%[fx:$xc-w/2]\n" info:`
offy=`convert actor.jpg -format "%[fx:$yc-h/2]\n" info:`
convert actor.jpg smiley.png +repage -gravity center -geometry +${offx}+${offy} -compose over -composite result1.jpg
```

[image]

Now, if we double the size of the smiley image to 300x300, we do not have to compensate further, because offx,offy are still center relative and the centers to do not change when the smiley is enlarged.

```
convert actor.jpg smiley.png +repage -gravity center -geometry 300x300+${offx}+${offy} -compose over -composite result2.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again for helping me forward.  Just working now on applying it to batch:   Would this be a reasonable starting point?
for file in facedetect/*.jpg; do
name=$(basename "$file"). i=0
facedetect  "$file" | while read -r x y w h; do

xc=`convert smileface.png +repage -format "%[fx:$xul + w/2]\n" info:`
yc=`convert smileface.png +repage -format "%[fx:$yul + h/2]\n" info:`

Comment: Yes, but you also need to compute the xoff and yoff variables. Also since you are getting -r x y w h, you need to use x in place of xul and y in place of yul.